# F# type mismatch when sending infix operator as parameter

Tags: function, types, f#, arguments, mismatch

I'm learning F# and is doing an exercise that requires me to perform math operations on a stack of floats.

```
exception InterpreterError;;
type Instruction = 
| ADD 
| SUB 
| MULT 
| DIV 
| SIN
| COS 
| LOG 
| EXP 
| PUSH of float;;

type Stack = S of float list;;

let pop (S(s)) = 
    match s with
    | [] -> raise InterpreterError
    | x::_ -> (x,S(s));;

let push x (S(s)) : Stack = S(x::s)

let applyBin f s : Stack = 
    let (first, sGen1) = pop s
    let (second,sGen2) = pop sGen1
    push (f(first,second)) sGen2;;

let applyUni f s : Stack = 
    let (first, sGen1) = pop s
    push (f(first)) sGen1;;

let intpInstr i s =
    match i with
    | ADD -> applyBin (+) s
    | SUB -> applyBin (-) s
    | MULT -> applyBin (*) s
    | DIV -> applyBin (/) s
    | SIN -> applyUni sin s
    | COS -> applyUni cos s
    | LOG -> applyUni log s
    | EXP -> applyUni exp s
    | PUSH(r) -> push r s;;
```

However, I'm getting a compiler error in the last function intpInstr on the infix operators (+, -, *, /) that I try to pass as arguments:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    float * float -> float    
but given a
    float * float -> 'a -> 'b    
The type 'float' does not match the type ''a -> 'b'
```

Why does the operators become (+) : float -> float -> 'a -> 'b? I haven't been able to replicate this type in the interactive console.
All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definition of `applyBin` the parameter `f` has type `(float * float) -> float` i.e. it takes a single pair parameter and returns a float. This is due to the application `f (first, second)` in `applyBin`. The binary operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` all have type `float -> float -> float` so it looks like you intend that to be the type of `f` within `applyBin`. You can do this by removing the pair construction:

```
let applyBin f s : Stack = 
    let (first, sGen1) = pop s
    let (second,sGen2) = pop sGen1
    push (f first second) sGen2
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thanks! I just assumed that it took a tuple since that's how I've been told to implement infix operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to invest into a custom composition operator, you could employ [eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) and express the logic of the function application more succinctly.

```
let (>|>) f g = f >> fun (b, c) -> g b c
let applyUna f = 
    pop >|> fun first ->
    push (f first)
let applyBin f = 
    pop >|> fun first -> 
    pop >|> fun second ->
    push (f first second)
```

There are still two tupled arguments returned by the 'pop' operation. Their conversion to curried arguments enables partial application and avoids the need to name any of the stack states.